# VPN PPTP server

Tags: vpn, tunnel, vpn-client

I'm doing a VPN PPTP server on this standard, now I have the following packages:

> **Client -> Server:**

```
Point-to-Point Tunnelling Protocol
Length: 156
Message type: Control Message (1)
Magic Cookie: 0x1a2b3c4d (correct)
Control Message Type: Start-Control-Connection-Request (1)
Reserved: 0000
Protocol version: 1.0
Reserved: 0000
Framing Capabilities: Either Framing supported (3)
Bearer Capabilities: Either access supported (3)
Maximum Channels: 1
Firmware Revision: 0
Host Name: anonymous
Vendor Name:
```

> **Client <- Server:**

```
Point-to-Point Tunnelling Protocol
Length: 156
Message type: Control Message (1)
Magic Cookie: 0x1a2b3c4d (correct)
Control Message Type: Start-Control-Connection-Reply (2)
Reserved: 0000
Protocol version: 1.0
Result Code: Successful channel establishment (1)
Error Code: None (0)
Framing Capabilities: Either Framing supported (3)
Bearer Capabilities: Either access supported (3)
Maximum Channels: 1
Firmware Revision: 0
Host Name: anonymouse
Vendor Name: anonymouse
```

> **Client -> Server:**

```
Point-to-Point Tunnelling Protocol
Length: 168
Message type: Control Message (1)
Magic Cookie: 0x1a2b3c4d (correct)
Control Message Type: Outgoing-Call-Request (7)
Reserved: 0000
Call ID: 63211
Call Serial Number: 22277
Minimum BPS: 1000
Maximum BPS: 100000000
Bearer Type: Either access supported (3)
Framing Type: Either Framing supported (3)
Packet Receive Window Size: 8192
Packet Processing Delay: 0
Phone Number Length: 0
Reserved: 0000
Phone Number: 
Subaddress:
```

> **Client <- Server:**

```
Point-to-Point Tunnelling Protocol
Length: 32
Message type: Control Message (1)
Magic Cookie: 0x1a2b3c4d (correct)
Control Message Type: Outgoing-Call-Reply (8)
Reserved: 0000
Call ID: 63211
Peer Call ID: 22277
Result Code: Connected (1)
Error Code: None (0)
Cause Code: 0
Connect Speed: 256
Packet Receive Window Size: 8192
Packet Processing Delay: 0
Physical Channel ID: 0
```

... but then it's not clear what should happen, the client does not send anything and everything hangs? Please tell me what is missing for the installation of the tunnel between the client and the server.

Comment: **Result Code: Connected (1)** Do you give the client access to the remote subnet ? Nothing happen if the client dont need remote ressource by the way :)

Comment: Warning: PPTP is obsolete and insecure. Do not use it if you require privacy or confidentiality.

Comment: @yagmoth555 ??))

Comment: @yagmoth555 My phone is waiting for a couple of seconds and writes that failed to establish a connection

Comment: The next step would be to exchange GRE packets. maybe your router or your setup blocks them.